# Consistent handling of transcription questions

Tags: discussion

This question... 
[What is the key of this song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/60967/what-is-the-key-of-this-song)
Is on hold for being off-topic. Apparently it is in the transcription category.

But why then is this question allowed?
[How would this rhythm be written out on a music staff?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/60995/how-would-this-rhythm-be-written-out-on-a-music-staff)
It's clearly a request to transcribe a basic music element.

Both questions have answers that attempt to show *how* to answer the question rather than merely transcribe or identify which hopefully is helpful for future questioners.

I don't think I have enough reputation yet to either put questions on/off hold. I'm just pointing out what I see as an inconsistency, because I can't take any other action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be closed and I just closed it. The accepted answer is "here it is" with no useful explanation. Tim's answer is somewhat useful for general purpose, but it's not what the OP wanted. For general rationale on why questions like this are closed [see this answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2392/7222).

Questions do slip thought the cracks from time to time and we need all the help we can get bringing issues like this to light. While you cannot cast close votes, you can flag it to go to the close vote queue where users with close/reopen votes can see it. It's been less than 24 hours since the question was posted so most likely not a lot of users with close vote privileges have seen it yet.

Comment: Thanks for updating me about the other question. I must find the flag to close option. Personally, I would rather get people to reword questions and keep them open, but I will try to help out with flagging things if necessary.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Putting questions "on hold" is just that -- temporary.  If they edit them into shape then we can re-open.

Answer (score 1):

I'm similarly confused about the blanket closure of any question which could involve the transcription of any element of a specific piece of music to answer.  In my case, I answered a [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/133161/how-to-achieve-a-similar-vibe-to-this-song/133162#133162) about what musical elements make a popular song seem "weird, dreamy" and so forth.  My answer involved transcribing a few measures to illustrate how certain chords work to achieve this effect and how they would apply to a large number of other songs.   Isn't that one of the most common functions of musical theory analysis?